# Id of repeater control not recognized in .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control inside a `carousel` which in turn is inside a `modal`.The problem is that the `id` of repeater control is not recogized or as it says `id dosent exist in current context`.

```
<div class="modal fade gallarymodal" id="mygallary" style=" width:1300px; height:100%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog mdialog">
<div class="modal-content" >

<div class="modal-body mbody">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">

  <asp:Repeater ID="repid" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div class="item" >
  <div class="item active">
  <asp:Image ID="wtf" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imgPath") %>' Width="1000px" Height="490px" />
  </div>
  </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
  </div> 
  </div>  
  </div>
```

And here is my .cs code

```
public void bindslide()
{
    //string str = Session["userid"].ToString();
    string str = "22";
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from mygallary where regId_img='" + str + "' ", sq.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    //da.Fill(ds);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        repid.DataSource = dt;
        repid.DataBind();
        sq.con.Dispose();
        sq.con.Close();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I am very much confused why the id `repeater control is not recognized`.

Comment: one of your div is missing a closing tag (`</div>`) and exactly where in your CS file do you get the mentioned error?

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio fails to add the corresponding field to your base class in code behind. Check to see if there is a field named `repid` defined.

Answer (score 0):

asp:Repeater ID="wtf"
asp:Image ID="wtf"

maybe the problem both got same id .
try change the id of one of them .

one closing tag on div missing

Comment: No it dosent change anything

Comment: in the code seems you have one div closing tag missing

Comment: copy past the code after adding closing tag to div and changing the id it seems to recognize the reapeter .

Comment: sorry for that..while editing the code here i by mistake removed it.